# Bad block, gas used error, Synchronisation failed

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, synchronization

I'm new to ETH. Just downloaded Mist 0.8.6 + Geth 1.4.18 and started geth.exe with these parameters:

```
geth --datadir C:\TMP\data --fast --cache=1024 --jitvm --jitcache 128
```

In Mist I saw a sync to 100%, but then it went back to 0% (and 1142 blocks remaining) and geth started to download some states.

But now it seems to be stuck in a loop:

> E1024 16:21:03.943468 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #2498274 (0x1601642df91
>   4cf016b79b25baee120af9b0163ed62333eee4879439227c91e18)
>   
> E1024 16:21:03.943468 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (469362 / 4659
>   62)
>   
> I1024 16:21:19.055332 eth/downloader/downloader.go:298] Synchronisation failed:
>   block download canceled (requested)
>   
> E1024 16:21:26.178740 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #2498274 (0x1601642df91
>   4cf016b79b25baee120af9b0163ed62333eee4879439227c91e18)
>   
> E1024 16:21:26.178740 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (469362 / 4659
>   62)

Restarting doesn't help.
The data dir has a size of 11.1GB.

What can I do now?
Thank you!

Comment: @stexacc32, please post your "EDIT: Hey ..." as an answer to your own question and self-accept your answer after a day or two. This will clear your question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had to remove --jitvm --jitcache 128 (even tried with default jitcache of 64). Now it's fully synced and no more errors.